# How to remove 'unremovable' consoles from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, console

I don't work with android all the time, sometimes I am working with a server/client app and I need to check the console output of both. What I used to be able to do was pressing the little blue monitor button on the console view to toggle between the two. But now it also have other 3 irremovable consoles(DDMS, OpenGL Trace View, Android) that I don't use, not even when developing for android. What I want to know is how to permanently remove those 3 console views. I don't want to have separated eclipse installations nor having to install/uninstall plugins whenever I am not developing for android.

I am prepared to delete/modify plugin source files, however I don't even know what I would be looking for

[image: What I want to remove]

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to modify .

1)Go to "**windows->open perspective**" and choose it for yourself

2) Or go to **windows->show perspective** select as it suits you.

Comment: You might be skipping 4 or 6 steps on how to disable those 3 specific console views, because I can't see how opening a perspective will help me

Comment: See modify all the perspective according to your server-client application
and go to " windows->save perspective " & save it as "client_server_perscp" . 

Now add required consoles from " windows->show perspective " like logcat, ddms etc and again save this perspective as  " android_prescp ".


Now every time you want to switch between the two just go to " windows->open perspective" and choose it  between client_serv_perscp or android_perscp.

Comment: I only have one console view available for me to use. That single one console view can toggle between consoles. It by default is opening with 'DDMS', 'OpenGL Trace View' and 'Android' as shown in the picture in the OP. What I want to do is not remove the console view, but to remove the consoles named 'DDMS', 'OpenGL Trace View' and 'Android' from the console view. As far as i know, this can't be done by messing with the perpective